# Bind ngOptions to array outside of scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to bind `ngOptions` to a value outside of the `$scope`?

I have a set of enums that will be automatically rendered as javascript. These are currently not part of "the angular domain", but I want to bind a `ngOptions` to one of the arrays, and I would like to not have to copy the items into the scope manually.

The reason why I want this is because I have some HTML Helpers which renders the items automatically, so I want a very generic solution without the need of adding a lot of code to the controller. Is that possible?

```js
var NS = NS || {};
NS.Sub  = NS.Sub || {};
// This is auto-generated:
NS.Sub.enums = {"deliveryStatus":[{"id":1,"label":"Delivered"},{"id":2,"label":"Expected"},{"id":4,"label":"Failed"}],"documentType":[{"id":0,"label":"Pdf"},{"id":1,"label":"Rtf"}]};


var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    // If I copy the items to the scope it works.
    $scope.items = NS.Sub.enums.deliveryStatus;
    $scope.model = {}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <p>Not working SELECT (bound to array outside of scope)</p>
    <select ng-model="model.status" ng-options="item.label for item in NS.Sub.enums.deliveryStatus"></select>
  
    <p>Working SELECT (bound to array inside scope)</p>
    <select ng-model="model.status" ng-options="item.label for item in items"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to bind using controller  or scope, As per my experience no other option is available.

Comment: @Satpal, thx, that's what I feared. Is it possible to fetch it from a service or something else? So that I at least can leave the controller a bit outside of it?

Comment: Yes, You can fetch the data from service and populate `$scope.items` from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/doxefuvijo/2/edit?html,js,output)
You can attach `NS` to the `$rootScope` and you can then use it on any controller by just calling it directly `NS`

```
app.controller('MainController', function($rootScope){

    var vm = this;
    var NS = { Sub: { } };
    //you just need to do this once
    NS.Sub.enums = {"deliveryStatus":[{"id":1,"label":"Delivered"},{"id":2,"label":"Expected"},{"id":4,"label":"Failed"}],"documentType":[{"id":0,"label":"Pdf"},{"id":1,"label":"Rtf"}]};
    $rootScope.NS = NS;
});
```

Simply use it like

```
<select ng-model="model.status" ng-options="item.label for item in NS.Sub.enums.deliveryStatus"></select>
```

Comment: Doing it in the controller will not help me, because then I just as well can copy the array and use it in my `$scope`. But if it's done in the `angular.module('myApp').run`it should work.

Comment: Sure you can just put it on `.run` the same effect will be achieved

Comment: will this work for Angular 2? I was under the impression they're getting rid of $scope in ng2

Answer (score 1):

In many apps, there is an initialization phase that loads up necessary assets (e.g. txt files, permissions, configs, etc.).  In my app, we load a config.txt prior to bootstrapping Angular.  So the order is something like this:

#### 1. use XmlHttpRequest to fetch the config.txt

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open( 'GET', './version.txt' );
```

#### 2. onLoad parse the txt file, assign values to a `values` obj

```
client.onLoad( function(){
    values = parse(client.responseText); //you'll have to define this

    bootstrapTheApp()
}
```

#### 3. define an angular `.value` that stores that in the angular realm

```
 angular.module( 'app', [] )
 .value( 'values', values )
```

#### 4. bootstrap your app

```
 bootstrapTheApp = function(){
     var ns = 'app' //this is basically the same thing as declaring `ng-app="app"` in your index.html
     angular.bootstrap( document, [ ns ] )
 }
```

Then later on in your controller you can just inject the values as you would any other injectable.

```
.controller( 'myController', function( $scope, values ){ 
     $scope.options = values.options
}
```

Now this looks a little strange and you'll have to arrange it based on the logic you need in the order you need. But this allows you to do things **before** angular starts it's *configuration/declaration* phase which usually happens as soon as your angular scripts load.  This simply delays that until you're ready.